# Lagrangian for system of particles with statistical distribution $f(x_1, ..., x_N)$

Tags: statistical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, many-body

For system of $N$ particles it is known that it is a good model to take Lagrangian to be (ignoring electromagnetism) $$L = \sum \limits_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{2}(m_i \mathbf{v}_i^2) -U(\mathbf{x}_1, ..., \mathbf{x}_N).$$

Now assume that there is a known distribution function $f(\mathbf{x}_1, ..., \mathbf{x}_N)$ which gives probability of finding particle 1 at $\mathbf{x}_1$, particle at 2 at $\mathbf{x}_2$, and so on.

Is there a known way to write some kind of effective Lagrangian
that incorporates our statistical knowledge? I guess that would mean that the number of variables reduces from $2N$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to some effective vector field.

I guess if we have statistical distribution (which is assumed to be sufficiently smooth) we have to go from Lagrangian to Lagrangian field theory description in a sense that there is some kind of Lagrangian density that depends on $f$. 
Also we have to make sure that in a limit of distribution being sum of delta functions it should give Lagrangian of $N$ particles mentioned before.

Comment: See [BBGKY hierachy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBGKY_hierarchy). These lecture notes might be of interest: https://www.physik.uni-bielefeld.de/~borghini/Teaching/Nonequilibrium/05_04.pdf

Comment: @Nephente Thanks! As far as I understand, in that approach, they do not use variational methods in a sense of field theory. They just write the distribution function and how it evolves. I am more interested in approaches trying to write some effective Lagrangian field density and finding a variational principle for that.